# Integrating Elastic Stack with TeamCity builds to aggregate all logs

Tags: logging, teamcity, kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat

I'm looking for information on integrating Elastic Stack with TeamCity for log aggregation of the various logs related to the one build chain.

The place I'm getting stuck is a good way to grab the logs from a running agent, which is currently running a build step I want the logs for.

I want Filebeat to monitor for new logs across all steps in a single build. Running the Filebeat docker image in a container in Step 1 unfortunately does not persist in to Step 2, as from what i can tell when Step 1 exists, it brings down the docker container with it.

Is there a way to monitor all steps in a build like this?

Additionally, I understand build logs for a particular build can be accessed through the Rest API at endpoint http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/downloadBuildLog.html?buildId

However, I'm using Filebeat to grab logs, and as far as I can tell Filebeat does not support grabbing logs from a HTTP endpoint, and will just grab the full file with every poll, instead of updating line by line.

Is there a way to "locally" access the file being served via the downloadBuildLog.html endpoint?

Thanks for any info to the above questions!